# Google Play requires that apps target API level 29 or higher, How if i want to compile SDK version 26?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, google-play

Google Play requires that apps target API level 29 or higher, How if i want to compile SDK version 26?
[Google Play requires that apps target API level 29 or higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6adnl.png)